# Free Windows driver or tool to horizontally flip my screen

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source

I'm using Windows 8 with only 1 laptop screen and I want to flip it horizontally, so it'd look like when you're standing in front of a mirror [edit: example is the Ready word in attached pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NAmg.gif). Win8 has some internal flipped display settings but all do it vertically. My onboard card Intel driver can't do it either. Quick searching on the net results in some apps like Mirroring360 or UltraMon, but it looks like the former is not free while the latter may require at least 2 displays, from what I read.

So, how can I do it? Are there other free apps that can do this?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "Free Windows driver to use my screen vertically"? You want something like this right? https://img.wonderhowto.com/img/71/60/63565128152706/0/rotate-display-linux-mac-windows-computers.1280x600.jpg

Comment: Let's reopen when doubts are cleared :-)

Comment: No... Well, you must have seen the letters painted on ambulance cars, right? It's mirrored.

Comment: Any driver or app or software in general is appreciated, provided that it's free... or you guys are kind enough to point to a cracked version :)

Comment: Oh I see, very interesting requirement! Just being curious, may I ask why you want this? :-)

Comment: Is it for a video beam? If so, video beams have that feature build in. I used to have a graphics card that had all those options and it was nothing fancy, have you digged through the manual?

Comment: Well, I do monthly challenges to myself. I'm a lefty & was trained to write by the right hand since young, so I don't know how to do it with my dominant one. Last month, which ended just yesterday actually, I've successfully finished a challenge that requires me to practice lefty-writing everyday. Though it feels easier now to scribe, I still have trouble reading those words because my brain are so accustomed with reading normally, and it is being reinforced everyday & right now with the screens I read. So I decided this month's challenge would be a mirrored-laptop one.]

Comment: To imagine what it looks like, you can try searching for some of Leonardo da Vinci's writings. It's quite hard for the brain, BTW. Smartereveryday demonstrates this effect with a reverse-bike in some of his videos.
Anyway, I don't want to fail this challenge just by not having an app for the computer to do it!